# Sample Variance question

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

The random variable

$$ S^2=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(X_i- \overline X)^2}{(n-1)} $$

is called the *sample variance*.

**A)** Show that $ (n-1)S^2=\left[\sum_{i-1}^n ((X_i-\mu)^2 \right]-n(\overline X-\mu)^2 $

(*Hint:* Start with $(n-1)S^2=\sum_{i-1}^n ((X_i-\mu)+(\mu-\overline X))^2 $)

**B)** Use result from A) to show that $ E[S^2]=\sigma^2 $

---

**A)**

So far I used the hint to obtain
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n [(X_i-\mu)^2+2[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline X)]+(\mu-\overline X)^2]   $$
$$ =\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n2[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline X)]+\sum_{i=1}^n(\mu-\overline X)^2 $$
$$ =\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n2[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline X)]+n(\mu-\overline X)^2 $$

My next step was to take the sum of the middle part but it got messy and didn't look like it would help me much. I know need to get rid of that middle part and also negate the third part - Is it possible to just negate the *n* and then switch the $\mu\ \text{and the} \ \overline X$?

Help! I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the middle portion, note that: $\mu-\overline{X}$ does not depend on the index $i$ in the sum and thus can be taken out of the sum.

In other words, $\sum_{i=1}^n2[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline X)]$ can be re-written as:

$$2(\mu-\overline X)\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)$$

Now, use the fact that $n \overline{X} =\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and simplify.

Comment: I still have a question regarding the third term, $ n(\mu-\overline X)^2 $. Is that just the same as $ n(\overline X-\mu)^2 $ because the squared values are equal?

Comment: Yes. Note: $(a)^2 = (-a)^2$